# Are there penalties for just using the new keyword instead of creating a class variable before calling the class method?

Tags: performance, code-standards

Example

(1)

```
var classVar = new class();

classVar.Method();
```

(2)

```
new class().Method();
```

I like the second way, less wordy.

Is there a performance difference?

Is it considered bad coding practice?

Comment: You can not name your class `class`. And you shouldn’t name your method `Method`, i.e. starting with an uppercase letter. Besides that, the answer is, it doesn’t matter all. Use whatever you prefer.

Comment: Is this Java? You should add a suitable tag.

Comment: I know this is supposed to be a simple example, but it’s too simple. If you use `new`, it’s because you want a specific instance, presumably with specific data. In that case you would use `new class(data)`. If that’s not the case, then the method is presumably static, so you don’t need `new` at all. Which way is this going?

Comment: the use of the name "class" was meant to make it as simple as possible.

Comment: Yes, but is the method supposed to be static?

Comment: What language is this?

Answer (score 0):

If your `Method()` doesn't use anything from that `class`, why is it defined there? You could use `namespace` instead.

The only difference between your (1) and (2) is that the class instance is destructed immediately in (2).

Comment: Well, _your_ reference to it is gone, but it could have stashed `this` somewhere.

Comment: I didn't add a variable in the method call because I was just trying to make it as simple as possible. Just asking opinions on any performance difference (if any) and if considered bad practice. Thx

Comment: @BenG if the instance of your `class` did not exist before the call to its `Method()`, this method should be a `static` in that class or, instead, in a namespace. Yes, there is a cost in creating an instance of your class, and it will be wasted here.

Comment: There is no such thing as “immediate destruction” in Java.

Comment: @Holger I swear there was no Java tag when I answered. I wouldn’t even read that question

Comment: Working in C# environment. I did not select Java tag, not sure how that got there. I only selected performance and code-standards.

Comment: It's not Java, Java has no var keyword.  Tag was added by an editor, removing it.

Answer (score 0):

in your case Method seems to be static (ie there is no useful data stored inside the instance of 'class' (note I am ignoring all the invalid / not recommended name issues). Assuming this is c# but all languages have the same ideas, you would go

```
public class class{ // ugh
   public void static Method(){
       Console.WriteLine("I am Method");
   }
}
```

now you can go

```
 class.Method();
```

so the code is neatly filed away inside 'class' but you dont have to pay any overhead.

If you really need to instantiate 'class' then presumably you need to do more than just call one method on it. In which case

```
new class().Method();
```

makes no sense, since you call create it, call a method and destroy it.

Really a more concrete example is needed